# Container class not appearing on navigation menu

Tags: menus

I want to render a menu with a container like this:

`<nav class="nav">`

However, the container is just rendering with the default class name applied which I don't want.

`<nav class="menu-main-nav-container">`

I can't understand where I'm going wrong. Here's my code:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'nav-menu' ) ) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 
'container' => 'nav', 
'container-class' => 'nav', 
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="clearfix %2$s">%3$s</ul>' ) );
}
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I have the same problem, container_class never appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
'container_class' => 'nav',
```

instead of

```
'container-class' => 'nav',
```

You can check out the parameters here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Thank you! Been a while since I did any PHP and I've been doing this all evening.